# how to repeat same Javascript code over multiple html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Note: Changed code so that images and texts are links.

Basically, I have 3 pictures all with the same class, different ID. I have a javascript code which I want to apply to all three pictures, except, the code needs to be SLIGHTLY different depending on the picture. Here is the html:

```
<div class=column1of4>
<a href="images/watermark_pic1.jpg"><img src="images/actual.jpg"  id="first"></a>
<a href="images/watermark_pic1.jpg"><div id="firsttext" class="spanlink"><p>lots of text</p></div></a>
</div>

<div class=column1of4>
<a href="images/watermark_pic1.jpg"><img src="images/fake.jpg" id="second"></a>
<a href="images/watermark_pic1.jpg"><div id="moretext" class="spanlink"><p>more text</p></div></a>
</div>

<div class=column1of4>
<a href="images/watermark_pic1.jpg"><img src="images/real.jpg" id="eighth"></a>
<a href="images/watermark_pic1.jpg"><div id="evenmoretext" class="spanlink"><p>even more text</p></div></a>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript for the id="firsttext":

```
$('#firstextt').hide();
$('#first, #firsttext').hover(function(){
 //in
  $('#firsttext').show();

},function(){
 //out
  $('#firsttext').hide();
});
```

So when a user hovers over #first, #firsttext will appear. Then, I want it so that when a user hovers over #second, #moretext should appear, etc.

I've done programming in Python, I created a sudo code and basically it is this.

```
text = [#firsttext, #moretext, #evenmoretext]
picture = [#first, #second, #eighth] 

for number in range.len(text) //over here, basically find out how many elements are in text


$('text[number]').hide();
$('text[number], picture[number]').hover(function(){
 //in
  $('text[number]').show();

},function(){
 //out
  $('text[number]').hide();
});
```

The syntax is probably way off, but that's just the sudo code. Can anyone help me make the actual Javascript code for it?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(".column1of4").hover(function(){
    $(".spanlink").hide();
    $(this).find(".spanlink").show();
});
```

Comment: Hm doesn't work for some reason, .spanlink isn't even 'hiding' :/

Comment: okay I changed up my code so that the images and text are links, does that make a difference?

Comment: it not the thing about link. javascript is different from python

Comment: Right but the code provided doesn't work for me, it doesn't hide #text, #moretext and #evenmoretext :/

Comment: it just didn't hide in the begining,you just add $(".spanlink").hide() before the first line. i had test it and it runs ok

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
$('.spanlink').hide();
$('.column1of4').hover(
  function() {
    // in
    $(this).children('.spanlink').show();    
  },
  function() {
    // out
    $(this).children('.spanlink').hide();
  }
);
```

It doesn't even need the ids.

Answer (score 0):

So, the way you would do this, given your html would look like:

```
$('.column1of4').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'img, .spanlink', function(ev) {
    $(ev.delegateTarget).find('.spanlink').toggle(ev.type === 'mouseenter');
}).find('.spanlink').hide();
```

But building on what you have:

```
var text = ['#firsttext', '#moretext', '#evenmoretext'];
var picture = ['#first', '#second', '#third'];
```

This is a traditional loop using a closure (it's better to define the function outside of the loop, but I'm going to leave it there for this):

```
// You could also do var length = text.length and replace the "3"
for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
    // create a closure so that i isn't incremented when the event happens.
    (function(i) {
        $(text[i]).hide();
        $([text[i], picture[i]].join(',')).hover(function() {
            $(text[i]).show();
        }, function() {
            $(text[i]).hide();
        });
    })(i);
}
```

And the following is using `$.each` to iterate over the group.

```
$.each(text, function(i) {
    $(text[i]).hide();
    $([text[i], picture[i]].join(', ')).hover(function() {
        $(text[i]).show();
    }, function() {
        $(text[i]).hide();
    });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPT2u/1/) with all three versions. Just uncomment the one you want to test and give it a go.

Comment: The 'building on what I have' seems to hide it but not show it :/

Comment: That's because I'm an idiot and was doing something incredibly stupid. I've updated with a jQuery way since you're already using it.

Comment: #firsttext, #moretext and #evenmoretext.. Also, I changed up the code so that everything are links, does that make a difference?

Comment: Okay so for your code, should I ignore (function(i) { and just do, for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) { $.each(text, function(i) {? Or should I keep the stuff after (function(i) { in there as well?

Comment: For the `for` loop, definitely need the closure, but you don't need `S.each`. So you can use one or the other, but not really mix and match. `$.each` is creating a loop and calling the function (which is the same thing that the closure is creating in the `for` loop. I'll separate those to make them more clear.

Comment: Hm, reading your code makes perfect sense, but it just doesn't seem to work for some reason, it doesn't hide #text, #moretext and #evenmoretext :/

Comment: I found the problem when I made the fiddle that I added. Take a look. I added all three versions. To comment one out just change the `/* */` above the block to `/* * /`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it :

```
$('.column1of4').click(function(){

    $(this); // the current object
    $(this).children('img'); // img in the current object

});
```

or a loop :

```
$('.column1of4').each(function(){
    ...
});
```

Dont use Id as $('#id') for multiple events, use a .class or an [attribute] do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, this is quite easy to accomplish:

```
$('.column1of4 .spanlink').hide();
$('.column1of4 img').mouseenter(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().find('.spanlink').show();
});
$('.column1of4 img').mouseleave(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().find('.spanlink').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your markup structure, you could use DOM traversing functions like `.filter()`, `.find()`, `.next()` to get to your selected node.

```
$(".column1of4").hover(function(){
    $(".spanlink").hide();
    $(this).find(".spanlink, img").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the image inside the div and used this code, [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/h47sv/):

```
$('.column1of4').each(function(){
    $('div', $(this)).each(function(){
        $(this).hover(
            function(){
                //in
                $('img', $(this)).show();
            },
            function(){
                //out
                $('img', $(this)).hide();
            });
    });
});
```

The general idea is 1) use a selector that isn't an ID so I can iterate over several elements without worrying if future elements will be added later 2) locate the div to hide/show based on location relational to `$(this)` (will only work if you repeat this structure in your markup) 3) move the image tag inside the div (if you don't, then the hover gets a little spazzy because the positioned is changed when the image is shown, therefore affecting whether the cursor is inside the div or not.

### EDIT

[Updated fiddle for additional requirements](http://jsfiddle.net/h47sv/1/) (see comments).

Comment: This doesn't seem to hide the text container :/

Comment: @user216485 What do you consider the text container? I don't see an element with class or ID of text container.

Comment: #firsttext, #moretext and #evenmoretext is what I meant by the text container

Comment: @user216485 That requirement wasn't in your question, but I have updated my answer to accommodate this. Please see my edit.